# How many ki points does a Way of the Astral Self monk have to spend to use both the Arms of the Astral Self and Visage of the Astral Self features?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, monk, archetype

The wording of the [Way of the Astral Self monk](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#WayoftheAstralSelf)'s features (TCoE, p. 50-51) seems vague.

The description of the [Arms of the Astral Self](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#ArmsoftheAstralSelf-2992431) feature says, in part:

> Your mastery of your ki allows you to summon a portion of your astral self. As a bonus action, you can spend 1 ki point to summon the arms of your astral self.

And the relevant part of the description of the [Visage of the Astral Self](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#VisageoftheAstralSelf-2992462) feature says:

> You can summon the visage of your astral self. As a bonus action, or as part of the bonus action you take to activate Arms of the Astral Self, you can spend 1 ki point to summon this visage for 10 minutes.

Does this mean an Astral Self monk can spend just 1 ki point to summon both the Arms and Visage of the Astral Self? Or does it cost 2 ki points to summon both?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### It costs 2 ki points to use both.

The [Arms of the Astral Self](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#ArmsoftheAstralSelf-2992431) feature description states (TCoE, p. 50):

> you can spend 1 ki point to summon the arms of your astral self

The [Visage of the Astral Self](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#VisageoftheAstralSelf-2992462) feature description states (TCoE, p. 50-51):

> you can spend 1 ki point to summon this visage

Summoning your Arms costs 1 ki Point, and summoning your Visage costs 1 Ki point, so using both requires spending a ki point for each feature. You can do both with the same bonus action by spending 2 ki points.

It can only be done with a single bonus action because Visage of the Astral Self explicitly says you can:

> As a bonus action, or **as part of the bonus action you take to activate Arms of the Astral Self**

If you could do both with a single ki point, it would have said so, as it does for using a single bonus action. Since it does not say so, you need to separately spend 1 ki point for each feature.